# CryptoJS Unable to Decrypt Data

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I have the following encryption method which uses CryptoJS to encrypt a password.

```
function encrypt() {
            var val = document.getElementById('password').value;
            var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('u/Gu5posvwDsXUnV5Zaq4g==');
            var ivec = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('5D9r9ZVzEYYgha93/aUK2w==');
            var dataString = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(val);
            var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(dataString.toString(), key,
                { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv: ivec });

            document.dform.plaintext.value = encrypted.toString();
            form.submit();
        }
```

The following decrypt method doesn't give me the desired result:

```
function decrypt() {
            var val = document.getElementById('password').value;
            var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('u/Gu5posvwDsXUnV5Zaq4g==');
            var ivec = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('5D9r9ZVzEYYgha93/aUK2w==');
            //var dataString = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(val);
            var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(val, key,
                { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv: ivec });

            document.dform.plaintext.value = decrypted.toString();
            //form.submit();
        }
```

Sample Ciphertext: y5uoJYFk1+QS2I4Wx7QnsBq8dGe30ucBNaXsTnNhTOE=

Plaintext: helloworld

Comment: Please look into this example https://embed.plnkr.co/0VPU1zmmWC5wmTKPKnhg/

Comment: Already googled a lot and seen several articles and code but didn't find a similar solution. I tried other ways as well, but it seems CryptoJS doesn't have a good documentation where it exactly says the inputs being taken. Also it that article it is defining custom key length which is not the case in my code. I am kind of new to CryptoJS and hence was looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: You are trying to decrypt your password.

Comment: Leave it. The code is working but double hexed. I converted the output from my code to ascii twice and it shows the real password.